# Webpack doesn't recognize function parameters

Tags: function, import, webpack, export

I have defined a function and want to pack everything with webpack using node. Here is the function:

```
var makeReq = require('./makeReq.js');
var api = "sampleApi";

function videosDetails(videos) {

    var n = videos.length;
    var ids;

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var id = videos[i];
        ids += id.toString() + ','  ;
    };

    var url = api.concat(ids);
    var req = makeReq.makeReq(url);

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        videos[i].details = req.items[i].contentDetails;
        videos[i].details = req.items[i].statistics;
    };

    return videos;
};

module.exports = {
    videosDetails: videosDetails()
}
```

I get the error when compiling on Chrome's Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at videosDetails (app.bundle.js:197)
at Object.<anonymous> (app.bundle.js:217)
at __webpack_require__ (app.bundle.js:20)
```

Do not understand why it is not recognized when it is a function parameter. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `videosDetails()` with no argument in:

```
module.exports = {
    videosDetails: videosDetails()
}
```

You export the return value of `videosDetails` not the function itself. As you're calling it with no arguments, `videos` will be undefined.

You probably wanted to export the function:

```
module.exports = {
    videosDetails: videosDetails
}
```